# i want to iterate through the nested tags in html code like a list or json file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

i have this code for example:

```
<div class = "las">
    <div class = "asas">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jill</td>
          <td>Smith</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Eve</td>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>80</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div class = "las">
</div class = "asas">
```

i have saved it in variable called "code", how can i acces the `<td>Smith</td>` tag for example like that: code[0][0][1][1]. i use Beautiful Soup and the only way i know to iterate through the nested tags is with .parents and .children which becomes pretty confusing

Comment: Maybe you can convert the table into `pandas` dataframe and select the data from it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

```py
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

code_str = '''
<div class = "las">
    <div class = "asas">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Age</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr>
        <tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
''' 
code = BeautifulSoup(code_str).div
```

---

> *how can i acces the `<td>Smith</td>` tag for example like that: `code[0][0][1][1]`*

> *I use Beautiful Soup and the only way I know to iterate through the nested tags is with .`parents` and `.children` which becomes pretty confusing*

[ So I'm guessing you won't be happy with just `code.div.table.select('tr')[1].select('td')[1]` or `code.select_one('div>table>tr:nth-child(2)>td:nth-child(2)')` or anything like that. ]

There's also [`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) [which returns a list instead of a generator like `.children`], but I would be careful about using *`code.contents[0].contents[0].contents[1].contents[1]`* because `.contents` can include whitespace <sup>(view [`code.table.contents`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zO6A.png) for example)</sup>.

You could remove the whitespaces between tags with [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```py
# import re
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
code = BeautifulSoup(re.sub('>\s*<', '><', code_str).div
```

and then `code.contents[0].contents[0].contents[1].contents[1]` should return `<td>Smith</td>`.

Or you could write a class that converts `.contents` to nested lists

```py
# import bs4
class indexableTag:
    def __init__(self, origTag:bs4.element.Tag, ignore_whitespace=True):
        self.tag = origTag
        self.tag_contents = [
            indexableTag(c) if isinstance(c,bs4.element.Tag) else c 
            for c in origTag.children
            if not (ignore_whitespace and isinstance(c,str) and not c.strip())
        ]
        
    def __getitem__(self, key): 
        return self.tag_contents[key]

code = indexableTag(bs4.BeautifulSoup(code_str).div)
```

and then `code[0][0][1][1].tag` should return the bs4 Tag `<td>Smith</td>`.

---

> *Maybe you can convert the table into `pandas` DataFrame and select the data from it.*
>     – [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75762021/i-want-to-iterate-through-the-nested-tags-in-html-code-like-a-list-or-json-file#comment133647964_75762021) by [AndrejKesely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely)

You can convert the table to a DataFrame with [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)<sup>([view DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvV7a.png))</sup>

```py
# import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_html(code_str)[0] ##-> df.loc[0]['Lastname'] #='Smith'
df_dict = df.to_dict() ##-> df_dict['Lastname'][0] #='Smith'
df_recs = df.to_dict('records') ##-> df_recs[0]['Lastname'] #='Smith'
```